# Deferred deep linking in android

Tags: android, deep-linking

How can we get deferred deep linking work when the android app is installed from any third party location other than Play Store, say GDrive or S3 bucket. How to pass intent data in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as this sounds, it's actually a bit complicated to implement. You probably already know about the [InstallReferrerReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver), but that's obviously only for the Play Store.

You basically need to come up with some way to store data *outside* the app before it is downloaded, and then retrieve it inside the app after installation. [Branch.io](http://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the team) does this by using unique link IDs, to which we can attach a data dictionary. When a user opens that link prior to downloading, we tag their device ID and then redirect them to the specified URL (e.g., GDrive or S3). We match the device ID again after the app is launched the first time. This allows us to pass an unlimited amount of data with each link, since the data isn't actually stored *in* the link itself

Comment: Is this true deferred deep linking (like with firebase)? Does a new user get a seamless conversion experience of clicking a link and then seeing the content in the app?

Comment: @DominicCerisano yes, it is! And yes they do. Firebase is a fairly bare-ones implementation of this concept compared to Branch, but fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: I just got my noodle around Instant Apps (IA) - I see branch.io has already included this new feature. I think I saw somewhere that having to install an app drops conversion by 95% (only 5% bother). Any numbers on how IA improves conversion? It seems to blur the line as to what conversion means, since it used to mean installs leading to sales.

Comment: @DominicCerisano that's an excellent point. We haven't seen huge adoption of Instant Apps yet so hard to collect data. Definitely something I'm interested to follow too though!